# Bootstrap's Scrollspy: Offset when Scrolling has different offset after page reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I've got a problem with my navigation scrollspy on my SPA-Website (Single Page Application). When i normal scroll on my site the offset is correct and navigation gets correct active class. Now when i stay somewhere on the page as example on "about", my navigation has the correct active class. But when i do a refresh of the website and my browser scroll me back to the same point, my navigation gets "contact" the active class whats actually is just under "about". After i scroll once down and up again i get "about" active again.

I tried couple of things but nothing worked.

---

**Update:**
I fixed the problem by giving all my sections min screen height:

```css
html {
  height:100% !important;
}

body {
  height:100%;
}

section {
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you mentioned though:

> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy_refresh&stacked=h

```
$(document).ready(function(){
removeSection = function(e){
    $(e).parents("body > div").remove();
    $('body').each(function(){
//Try this refresh method if you haven't already.
        $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
    });
}
$("body").scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is your issue resolved? Or is your console returning anything?